# Angular 5 not able to post data on server

Tags: http, post, angular5

Hi I am new to angular 5
I am doing a demo project but i am not able to post data on server from some angular reference book i got this logic to send data but it is not working

```
 let params = new HttpParams();
params.set('action','CATEGORY');
this.http.post(this.url,{params}).subscribe(res => console.log(res.text()));
```

It working with GET method.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular provide `HttpClient` to use http methods ,  you should import like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
```

and then use service to contact with server

you can create a service by `ng g service yourservice` command

in your constructor ready httpclient instance like this and also write a function to contact  with server when we need:

```
 export class yourService {
       constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

      }

getData(data) {
      return this.http.post("your destinition url", data)
    }
}
```

and in each component you like you can call the function via service

```
export class SimpleComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private _service: yourService) {
  }



  ngOnInit() {
   let data = {id: 1} // everthing you need pass in request this is just a example
    this._service.getData(data).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data) 
    }
}
```

data contain server response and your result